# Docker info shows containers but docker container ls doesn't

Tags: docker

When I run `docker info`, it shows that I have 18 containers running.

```
% docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 18
  Running: 18
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 9
...
```

I want to delete these containers, but when I run `docker container ls -a`, it shows an empty list. How can I find them?

These containers are not allowing me to delete images.

```
% docker rmi -f 1e94481e8f30
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 1e94481e8f30 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 7e9b08a0007b
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more info in regards to your setup? e.g. if you are using docker desktop with kubernetes enabled - if so that would explain the running containers and why you can't delete them

Comment: what is the result of `docker ps`

Comment: @ClemensKaserer Just like you suspected, I had a docker desktop with kubernetes enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running kubernetes.

After stopping kubernetes, to remove all stopped containers and all images without at least one container associated to them:

```
docker system prune --all
```

Answer (score 2):

To stop all running containers

> docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

To remove all containers

> docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

You should be able to delete all images after that

Answer (score 2):

Those 18 containers belong to Kubernetes. You can check this by going to the Preferences > Kubernetes > Check `Show system containers (advanced)`.

After that, just run `docker container ls -a` again and you will see those 18 containers.

These are the containers you are not seeing unless you check that option:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6c3c65d4bcf4        a8c3d87a58e7           "/compose-controller…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_compose_compose-6c67d745f6-sr4zj_docker_34e7ef25-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
663d6419ce76        eb516548c180           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_coredns_coredns-6dcc67dcbc-2twts_kube-system_0c8d1f5f-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
d04a4caf922d        eb516548c180           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_coredns_coredns-6dcc67dcbc-chk2l_kube-system_0c8df4b4-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
324d5d216b07        f3591b2cb223           "/api-server --kubec…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_compose_compose-api-57ff65b8c7-svv9t_docker_34e161f1-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
f9f74acd5ab6        849af609e0c6           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-w4x7l_kube-system_0c95526c-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
3cbfa75f1466        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_compose-6c67d745f6-sr4zj_docker_34e7ef25-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
f11f1cc4bbba        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_coredns-6dcc67dcbc-chk2l_kube-system_0c8df4b4-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
cbb52fdaf130        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_coredns-6dcc67dcbc-2twts_kube-system_0c8d1f5f-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
5ad88766f27d        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_compose-api-57ff65b8c7-svv9t_docker_34e161f1-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
9f326ea7db5d        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-proxy-w4x7l_kube-system_0c95526c-166e-11ea-857d-025000000001_2
ea36a7a0d248        f1e3e5f9f93e           "kube-scheduler --bi…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-docker-desktop_kube-system_ef4d089e81b94aa15841e51ed8c41712_2
f3dfa711ea0f        1e94481e8f30           "kube-apiserver --ad…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-docker-desktop_kube-system_b1dff398070b11d23d8d2653b78d430e_2
1e5cf76eaf20        2c4adeb21b4f           "etcd --advertise-cl…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_etcd_etcd-docker-desktop_kube-system_3773efb8e009876ddfa2c10173dba95e_2
d631fca0d4ac        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-docker-desktop_kube-system_ef4d089e81b94aa15841e51ed8c41712_2
20242b387b05        36a8001a79fd           "kube-controller-man…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop_kube-system_86e291a2049db314a5eca69a05cf6ced_2
b32c2d63090f        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-docker-desktop_kube-system_b1dff398070b11d23d8d2653b78d430e_2
4d6e49f60ead        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_etcd-docker-desktop_kube-system_3773efb8e009876ddfa2c10173dba95e_2
9035ccdcae5d        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop_kube-system_86e291a2049db314a5eca69a05cf6ced_2
```